# jQuery .append once at a time only (currently occurs multiple times)

Tags: jquery, append

I am having a problem with an append.  I am using "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" instead of onhover so that the append isn't happening a million times, however I am still having an issue with people entering and leaving their mouse multiplte times on the div.

To see the issue, please goto http://mercury-consulting.theportlandco.com/ and put your mouseover "cloud based" in the banner about 20% of the way down the page.   If you then move your mouse away and then back over again several times in succession, the append occurs multiple times creating layers and layers.

This is an example of my code:

```
$("#cloud1").live("mouseenter", function() {
$(this).append('<div class="cloud1" style="display:none"><img src="http://mercury-consulting.theportlandco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/1.png" width="470" height="270"/></div>')
.find('div.cloud1').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1100); 
});

$("#cloud1").live("mouseleave", function() {
$(".cloud1").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1100, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
});
```

Comment: ur remove the cloud1 after mouseleave!!!

Comment: Hey man hover and append div ids are same!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `.stop()` before the `.show()` and `.hide()` it will stop the animation

Answer (score 2):

Use `.stop(true, true)` on the object being animated to cancel the preceding animation.

---

**Edit:** actually looking at your code you could do something allow the following:

```
$('#cloud1, #cloud2, #cloud3').hover(function() {
    var id =  $(this).attr('id');

    // If a div isn't already available/animating, then create it
    if (!$('div.' + id).length)
    {
        // Create and show the div
    }
  }, function() {
    // slide the div down
  }
);
```

Comment: nice, i didn't know about those parameters

Answer (score 0):

You could have a flag and verify if it is turned off, and if so, then append the layer and turn the flag on; else, don't append the layer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code still has problems. Check the screenshot I took after you implemented `stop()` in your site:

[image]

Reproduce the bug by keeping mousing over and out the activation div ('Cloud based' for example) a couple of times **before** the show animation ends, then just stop the mouse over 'Cloud based'.

What others said (verifying if there is already a `.cloud1` layer there) can be integrated in your solution with `append(function (idx,html))` syntax (doc is [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/)):

```
$("#cloud1").bind("mouseenter", function() {
    $("#cloud1").append(function(idx, html) {
        if ($(html).find('.cloud1').size() == 0) {
            return '<div class="cloud1" style="display:none"><img src="http://mercury-consulting.theportlandco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/1.png" width="470" height="270"/></div>'; 
        }
    }).find('.cloud1').stop().show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1100);
});
```

Finally, I used `bind` instead of `live` because:

> This method (live()) is a variation on the basic .bind() method for attaching event handlers to elements. When .bind() is called, the elements that the jQuery object refers to get the handler attached; **elements that get introduced later do not**, so they would require another .bind() call.

Since you have only one #cloud1, and no others are introduced later, you don't need live().